# How can I delete all space in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I create a table then I write the data, but all data looks like with space.

[image]

My data type is;

[image]

How can I delete all data's space in a table?

**NOTE**: BTW, I just fill a cell then I press "`Tab`" for passing next cell. This is a weird situation. Is `TAB` button add these spaces?

**EDIT**: This is not `TAB`'s crime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `nchar(10)` must always be 10 characters long.  So they're padded with spaces.  A variable length string uses the `nvarchar` datatype.

Change the column type to `nvarchar(10)` should remove the trailing whitespace; if it doesn't, you could use a query like this:

```
update  YourTable
set     P_Type = rtrim(p_type)
```

Comment: I would add ltrim as well, who knows how data was inserted

Comment: It looks like a normal `varchar` will do as long as the correct collation is set.

Comment: @Andomar Thanks for information. But your query didn't work :s In my table, they still have space after run your query. Also when try to change my datatype i getting this error. http://imgur.com/XDOvK

Comment: They are all right. You have to change the datatype Nvarchar, otherwise the remaining char places are filled with space

Comment: @Soner Gönül: That probably means that you have a foreign key to a table called `PARAMS`.  You'll have to change the data type in both places, which can be tricky.  Perhaps it's an option to leave the table unchanged, and `rtrim` whenever you retrieve data from the table?

Answer (score 3):

> How can I delete all data's space in a table?

Your can not. You asked for it.

Data type: nchar(10) = 10 characters, padded with spaces.

Use nvarchar(10) - variable length - then update with proper trim to get rid of the spaces.

Comment: @TomTom I tried to change my datatype from `nchar` to `nvarchar` but i getting this error http://imgur.com/XDOvK

Comment: Well, then please please plaese read the manual. In the meantime in options allow the editor to drop and recreate tables when needed. It normally throws an error when it has to do so on a table change - you wont loose data.